# Restrict record creation through field values & public groups

Tags: permissions, approval-process

I've created an app which can be used to create new requests to be sent through an approval process for employees by their managers. The functionality works great but I am now trying to think of the best approach for permissions\restrictions.

The requests will be created with a custom button within a custom object called the "Employee Profile". (employee__c). I want only the Manager of that employee - and THAT manager's manager to be able to create the requests, along with a restricted group of other executives who would be able to create a request for whoever they want.

Right now the manager and the manager's manager are both represented in fields in the employee__c record.

I have ideas of how I could accomplish this but I'm not sure if they're the best approach. Since the request is created with a Flow (launched by the custom button) then I suppose I can simply stop the flow from advancing once I determine the user isn't one of the managers listed in the employee__c record. But I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Also, I'm not really sure how to refer to a public group in this type of Flow logic, so I don't know how I would be able to allow the group of executives to submit a request for anybody.

Any suggestions as to the best approach on this ? I feel like I'm jumping through hoops when there must be a much easier approach. But I can't really see how Roles or even Profiles could be applicable here.

Comment: if the users who you dont want to submit belong to a role or profile or have a specific value in a user object custom field, then i believe this can be added in approval criteria. if you want to restrict who can see these requests, then that can be set using owd, sharing settings or profile permissions. If you still want to go with Flow logic, you can query the Group object to see if the user who is submitting is present in the public group. Hope this helps

Comment: I guess you're talking about the entry criteria prohibiting them to submit a request ? I guess that would work for referring to a field value, but can I refer to a Public Group in the entry criteria ? I really don't like the idea of using the entry criteria because it gives such a vague error message.

Comment: yes i was referring to entry criteria. I dont think public group can be added in entry criteria. so if you using flow then probably SOQL on group object can be used to display meaningful errors. The other option is to build custom approval process using apex code and corresponding visualforce screens to display message. But i would rather go for Flow instead of completely new vf screens & custom apex approval processes.

Comment: Thank you very much Asif. Great advice. I didn't know you could use the Group object in that way. So I guess I'll just use Flow logic to determine if it's the Manager or Manager's Manager - and if not then refer to the Group to determine if it's a member of the group in question. Thanks again !